# Smooth curved shapes in opencv, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to create filled smooth curves and save it in .png file using python. The example of what I would like to get is this:

[image]

The shape of this closed curve is not important, the only requirement is that it should be smooth and closed.

Is it possible to generate such curves using OpenCV, or should I use another library?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but what kind of equation would govern the shape of this object? Once you have some kind of rules/equation which govern the shape of the object, then you can simply create a list of *(x, y)* and use `cv2.drawContours()` method to draw the shape, but you may need to study the format in which points are stored in `cv2.drawContours()`

Comment: if smoothness is your main criteria you should use spline curves. Since openCV is a computer vision library, it isn't perfect for such application (which is more about computet graphics).

Comment: Yes, smoothness is the main goal. But after that I need to fill that closed contour. Is it possible with spline curves?